# How should I pass latexdiff options to latexdiff-vc?

Tags: latexdiff, revision-control, git

I use `latexdiff-vc -r paper\paper.tex` to diff my current .tex file relative to the version most recently committed to a Git repo.
If citations do not change between versions, this command works great.
However, if citations change between versions, I need to use `latexdiff`'s `--disable-citation-markup` option.
The `latexdiff-vc` help file suggests that I can pass the `--disable-citation-markup` option to `latexdiff-vc`:

```
latexdiff-vc [ latexdiff-options ] [ latexdiff-vc-options ] -r [rev1] [-r rev2] file1.tex [ file2.tex ...]
```

When I pass the `--disable-citation-markup` option to `latexdiff-vc`, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\richa\Research\payout-and-gov41-paper>latexdiff-vc --disable-citation-markup -r paper\paper.tex
Guess you are using GIT ...
Working on  paper\paper.tex
patching file paper/paper.tex
Running: latexdiff  '--disable-citation-markup' "paper\paper-oldtmp-18928.tex" "paper\paper.tex" > "paper\paper-diff.tex"
2 and only 2 non-option arguments required.  Write latexdiff -h to get help
C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 2:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff.pl '--disable-citation-markup' "paper\paper-oldtmp-18928.tex" "paper\paper.tex"
Something went wrong in latexdiff. Deleting paper\paper-diff.tex and abort
C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 5:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff-vc.pl --disable-citation-markup -r paper\paper.tex
```

The problem may be that `latexdiff-vc` wraps the `--disable-citation-markup` option in single quotes.
My current solution is to copy-and-paste the failed command, remove the single quotes, and rerun.
Is there a better solution that avoids copying-and-pasting and manually deleting the `latexdiff-vc` temporary files?

FWIW, I use TeX Live on Windows 10.

Comment: Would it work if you replaced the single quotes with double quotes? (I am the developer of latexdiff and only have access to linux for testing, and unfortunately little time to work on latexdiff these days). The quotes are there to keep commands with spaces together, and special characters safe from the shell.

Comment: @frederik The single quotes around `--disable-citation-markup` are added by `latexdiff-vc`. I type my `latexdiff-vc` command without quotes. I get the same results if I wrap `--disable-citation-markup` with single or double quotes. No worries if this is Windows-specific. The time you've saved me editing is well worth the _small_ step of running a command, deleting quotes, and running a command! Thanks!

Comment: In the original implementation latexdiff-vc did not add the quotes but this lead to trouble for some users (which is why they were introduced). Probably there is some universal solution (e.g. quotes only around the arguments), but without a way to test this behaviour easily, I will probably not embark on fixing this.  Glad to hear latexdiff has been useful to you.